# Excel VBA Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I want to a macro for excel vlookup

My current mcaro is:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-86],'2PM'!C[-86]:C[-54],33,0)"
```

I want to select a lookup_value from a specific column eg I4

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(I4,'2PM'!C[-86]:C[-54],33,0)"
```

Comment: You want it always to refer to the forth row on column I or the row in which the formula is placed?

Comment: I want to refer it to I4 i.e forth row of column I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing A1 and R1C1 notation.  They must match:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R4C9,'2PM'!C[-86]:C[-54],33,0)"
```

The `R4C9` will always refer to column I row 4.

Comment: Can you please share with me the code with I4 notation?

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way I can change Macro code to A1 notation?

I am not familiar with R1C1 notation,

Comment: Yes, change `.FormulaR1C1` to `.Formula` and change ***ALL*** the references to A1 format.